# Volumes and integration - slicing method help.

Tags: integration, volume

[image: help]

So with this question as seen in the image I have completed everything except part c) - part iv) and I am really stumped as to what to do. I am not sure about the borders I should integrate against but I do know part c) - part iii) must be used in regards to the integration. Please help. Thank you :)

Comment: We want $\int_0^\infty \pi e^{-2x}\sin^2 x\,dx$. It will be an integration by parts, much like the one you have already done for area. The work may feel more routine to you if you use the identity $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x$ to rewrite $\sin^2 x$ as $\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$.

Comment: how did you obtain this as an area: πe^(−2x)sin2x

Comment: @AndreNicolas I agree with you, but does this seem to give the answer they have?

Comment: @betty_carr: Sorry about lateness in replying-was cooking. The volume obtained by rotating the region between $y=f(x)$ and the $x$-axis, from $x-a$ to $x=b$, is $\int_a^b \pi(f(x))^2\,dx$. So I squared out function.

Comment: @user84413: I get $\frac{\pi}{8}$ for the volume.

Comment: @AndreNicolas Thanks for your reply; that's what I got, too.

Comment: so how is it that we may attain the answer wanted